# Google chrome Delete Web Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

im using vscode to use a web api, and using the method get it works perfectly, but when i use Delete it gives an error.
That error only appears with google chrome because with IE it works.

Here is the code:

`function ApagarItem(value)
{
        var settings = {
        "url": "the link",
        "method": "DELETE",
      }
 
     $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
}`

For the get code to work i had to add an extension in chrome to enable cross-origin resource sharing

The errors are the following:

OPTIONS "The Link" 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Failed to load "The Link": Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: As the error says, you can't use the DELETE method

Comment: The issue is with your backend, not your frontend. The server needs to be set up to properly handle CORS - see https://enable-cors.org/server.html for info on how to do so.

Comment: Heres my code:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="Homepage()">
    <div id="DivMestre">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: but how?.............................

Comment: You have to set an HTTP-Header to your servers responses telling the browser that Cross origin requests are allowed. The header you have to set is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which you can set to `*`which allowes requests from all origins. Be aware of the **security implications** when allowing cross origin requests! Good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS